# CSS placing one image on top of another

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am working on CSS design template.

I have two images `imageOne` and `imageTwo`.

Both are `position: relative` because if I set one of them `position: absolute` then it does not stay as responsive anymore and responsiveness is the key here.

What I want is to place `imageTwo` on top of `imageOne`.

How can I achieve that while twitterbootstrap's responsive feature still works on these two images?

Below is my code: (jsfiddle available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/doforumda/uS7nw/1/))

```
<div class="imageOne image"></div>
<div class="imageTwo image"></div>
```

CSS

```
.image {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.imageOne {
    z-index: 0;
}
.imageTwo {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: i think this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/29u8S/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I've added a wrapper div for those images, with position relative and changed `.image { position: relative` to `absolute` and it worked for me.
http://jsfiddle.net/uS7nw/2/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="imageOne image"></div>
    <div class="imageTwo image"></div>
</div>
```

And

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.image {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: I think the PO doesn't want to use position:absolute

Answer (score 9):

When you have elements within a `container` which has the property: `position: relative;`
then any elements within that container which have the property: `position: absolute;`
will have their offset origin set to the top-left of the container.

For example,

```
<div class="relative"> <!-- top: 50px; left: 100px; //-->
  <div class="absolute"></div> <!-- top: 0; left: 0; //-->
  <div class="absolute"></div> <!-- top: 10px; left: 20px; //-->
</div>
```

The first absolute child will be positioned at (50px, 100px) relative to the `body`, or (0,0) from the `container`.

But the second child will be positioned at (10px, 20px) relative to `container`, or (60px, 120px) relative to the `body` (add 50+10 from the top, 100+20 from the left).

Answer (score 4):

If you have a responsive image in a container and want to place another image on top of that image:

HTML:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;/*Or whatever you want*/
}
.imageOne {
  width: 100%;
}
.imageTwo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="imageOne" src="https://www.google.no/images/srpr/logo11w.png">
  <img class="imageTwo" src="https://news.ycombinator.com/y18.gif">
</div>
```

Comment: I like this one, but keep getting some margin/padding below the google logo in the container div. I'm trying heigth:50% on the 'Y' and would expect to correctly place it in bottom left corner with top:50% (or 20%-80%) but it's slightly off. Any hints?

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to wrap both of them in a div with `position:relative`

```
<div style="position:relative">
<div class="imageOne image"></div>
<div class="imageTwo image"></div>
</div>
```

Then give both of the images an absolute position

```
.image {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/uS7nw/4/

```
.imageTwo {
    z-index: 1;
    background:red;
    margin-top: -42px;
}
```

Comment: that's div not **image**

Comment: that s a class called .imageTwo you can apply at any DOM element you want

Comment: can be like this `<image src="../" class="imageTwo">` ?

Comment: yep exactly or <div class="imageTwo"> ...</dv> -- :D

Answer (score 1):

```
.imageTwo {
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: -100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `position: relative;` to `position: absolute;`

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uS7nw/3/)

If you still want a relative position, wrap the absolute in another `div`.