# Combine 2 divs and 1 img into 1 img?

Tags: php, html

I want to achieve the following:

1. Display an image inside a `<div>` element.
2. Image is served using a image-server-php (`image.php`) to "mask" the image location.
3. The image should be *clickable* with another link opening after click.
4. Image is hidden behind a *sorry.gif* to make sure that the user cannot "right click and save image".

Below is my code:

```
<!-- IMAGE FRAME -->
<div class="img-frame">
    <!-- CLICKABLE TO TAKE TO ANOTHER PAGE --> 
    <a href="javascript: void(0)" OnClick="window.open('page1.php'); return false;" class="img-preview" title="Click here for more info" >
        <!-- COVER IMAGE TO STOP PPL DOWNLOADING IMAGES -->
        <div class="CoverImage">
            <!-- IMAGE SERVED VIA A IMAGE-SERVER-PHP -->
            <img src="image.php?f=three.jpg" class="scale-with-grid" width="300px" height="275px" />
            <div class="cover"><img src="assets/mm/sorry.gif" class="scale-with-grid"/></div>
        </div>
        <!-- END COVER IMAGE -->    
    </a>
    <!-- END CLICKABLE -->
</div>
<!-- END IMAGE FRAME --->
```

Is there a way I can merge the two images into one, in the same `<img>` element?

I need it inside the `<img>` element because I use `prettyPhoto` for gallery creation.

Comment: So...HTML inside an image? :)

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv well not really. I want to know if there was a way to do something like this `<img src=image.phpf=three.jpg class="blah" coverimage="sorry.gif" href="java.." onclick=="window.open"... </img>`

Comment: There's no such thing as `coverimage` built-in. Also, no `href` on anything else but `a`.

Comment: @Sergiu `coverImage`- I have got all that defined and working correctly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hiding the image behind another one is a technique that will work only against non-technical users. Be aware of that.

A tech-savy user will simply browse the source code of your page.

This can be achieved by using CSS.
What you want to have is two images, the one you want to serve overlayed with sorry.png with transparency set to 100%.
Then the sorry.png should be linking to page1.php

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
.image {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.imageOne {
    z-index: 0;
}
.imageTwo {
    z-index: 1;
}

<div class="container">
<div class="imageOne image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/000"></img>
</div>
<div class="imageTwo image"> <a href="page1.php">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/fff">

    </img>
    </a>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uS7nw/2/)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235709/css-placing-one-image-on-top-of-another)

Comment: Thanks @Marcin but using a image-server-php I am masking the image location, is it still possible to download the image?

Comment: Can you give me a link to that "image-server-php"?

Comment: in my case the user cannot use  `www.mywebsite.com/image.php?f=three.jpg` to access the image directly from the browser.  I use `.htaccess` and `image.php?onlyHappensFromHTACCESS=denied` to make sure that the image gets accessed only via the main php

Comment: If the image is transmitted to the user and displayed to him, than the user will have that image, no matter how you secure it. If you set up such a page, I can demonstrate how to do that. (Source: Kind of interested in web scraping)

Comment: Yes you are correct, if someone is intent on scraping stuff from the website they will find a way :-). My methodology will hopefully stop "opportunistic scrapers".

Comment: How sophisticated is your audience? If not that much, using right-click blocker might be a better option.

Comment: if I use a right-click blocker can i combine everything else into one `<img>`?

Comment: Yes. Right-click blockers, only affect right-click, nothing else. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, I will get back to this in couple of days and will let know if it works for my case :-).

Comment: going through your proposed answer I realised  that your solution is exactly the same as showcased in my question. using 2 `<div>` and 2 `<img>`. I do admit that yours looks more elegant than mine but it does not address my question.

Comment: Check out my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since my previous answer wasn't exactly what you wanted but still feels relevant to me,here is another one.

To achieve what you want using one IMG tag you should use the background-image CSS property.

That means you have an IMG tag with transparent sorry.gif that has CSS property like so:

```
.imageSorry
{
    background-image:url('three.gif');
    opacity:1;
}
```