# Proper overlapping of images in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image and I want to overlap a gif image inside that?
I am able to add the image inside another, but I want that the image should be added properly inside another one.

Any suggestion how I can do that?

code that I am using currently is

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
                            <img src="" width="225" height="140"  />
                            <img src="light bulb image" alt="member1" title="member1"
                                 style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;"/>
                            <img src="another gif image" style="position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 70px;"/>
                        </div>
```

Comment: do you have a snippet / jsfiddle?

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235709/css-placing-one-image-on-top-of-another

Comment: No i dont have one, but i can share the images,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer for the problem, anyone who has similar problem can take help from this link and solve the issue.
I assumed the upper part of the image kind of circle shape and solved the problem.
https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/53261baf548c35ac9a010422

Answer (score 1):

Use `position` and `z-index` to control the layer. Generally the element with `position:absolute` will stay at the top of  other elements in the parent container use `z-index` to controll more layers. An example -

```
<style>
#img2{
    left:20px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:0;
}
</style>
<div>
   <image id="img2" src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/light-bulb-clip-art-idea-light-bulb-md.png"/>
   <image  src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/white-canvas-background_1053-239.jpg"/>
</div>
```

For live example -https://jsbin.com/narakozeki/edit?html,output