# Angular 2 animate - changing element attribute

Tags: angular

The angular 2 animate documentation is very poor, so I started playing with it and decided to make some nice animation like fading, between 2 images.

My current image has the animation trigger all set up:

```
<img src="myimage.png" class="img img-responsive"
            [@travelState]="travelState"
            >

animations: [
    trigger('travelState', [
      state('inactive', style({

      })),
      state('active',   style({
//Change image src
      })),
      transition('inactive => active', animate('100ms ease-in')),
      transition('active => inactive', animate('100ms ease-out'))
    ])
  ]
```

Now, switching between inactive state and active state has to change the image `src` attribute to another image, with fading transition.
How I can change the `src` image attribute when the image triggers active state?

Answer (score 1):

Angular 2 animations are built on top of the W3C's CSS3 transitions API. As you can see from their [list of animatable properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties), you **cannot** animate the `src` property.

You can, however, achieve essentially the same effect by layering both images on top of each other (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18235788/5386466) if you need help doing that) and animating the opacity of whichever image is on top.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use the `onDone` callback that will be included in RC.6

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10304

Comment: Cool, thanks. So until then I can apply only CSS styles such as backgroundImage to an animation state?

Comment: I haven't used animation myself yet and have actually no idea what you're talking about :D I just remembered seeing this issue and related PR and got the impression this is related.